# Facebook FQL share_count is always 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

FQL: `SELECT share_count FROM stream WHERE post_id = "19292868552_10150189643478553"` returns 0

I have tried with another posts and every time it's 0

Is there another way how to get people who shared post ?
Like to get likes: `https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553/likes`

Answer (score 0):

If you run your graph URL in Facebook explorer then you will see that this post has no share_count. So there's nothing bad with the response.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in order to access the share_count property of a post in both the graph api and FQL stream table the access token used must have the **read_stream** permission. 
I have noticed this stands true only for some pages as there are cases when you can access the share_count without the extended permission.